# Gap between top header and Navigation bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am in the process of building a custom template in Wordpress but I have a big gap between the top and bottom (nav) part of the header which should only be 1px.

Any help on how I can fix this?

Thanks
Dee

http://serenityhouse3.ayomo.com

Comment: Please add some code, we can't help you if we can't see what you are doing/what you tried

Comment: easy fix :-    #header {    margin: 0 0 -15px 0; } in your css.

A more appropriate fix, I need to take a closer look.

Comment: Within your styles.css you'll want to set `ul#mainNav{margin-top: 0px;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
ul#mainNav{
   margin-top: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-top: 0px` to the **ul#mainNav** like this:

`ul#mainNav {margin-top: 0px}`

and `margin: 0 0 1px 0;` to the **#header** like this:

`#header{margin: 0 0 1px 0;}`

Comment: I agree with Adam. Except the user wants 1px margin between header and nav; so ..... #header{ margin: 0 0 1px 0}

Answer (score 0):

```
 ul#mainNav{

       margin: 1px;

 }
```